# Determine if UIViewController is closing due to application exit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to test in **viewWillDisappear** if it's being called because the application is exiting, versus normal ways of it being dismissed?  The method **applicationWillTerminate** in the App Delegate is called *after* the current view is closed.  I want to do different things depending on whether it's being dismissed due to a IBAction or the user clicking the menu button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use observe the `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` in your controller, set a flag, and then check for the flag in your `viewWillDisappear` implementation.

```
NSNotificationCenter* defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self       
                  selector:@selector(applicationWillTerminate:)
                      name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification
                    object:nil];
```

Comment: I'm seeing that viewWillDisappear gets called before that notification. So how will setting flags matter?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it for your purposes yet, but the **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** notification might occur before  **applicationWillTerminate** is called.

Just throw...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResign:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:NULL];
```

... into your UIViewController to test it out.

Comment: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification doesn't seem to be getting triggered when the application is closed due to the menu button.  applicationWillTerminate always fires, though.